# Is it possible to run chrome in integrated Intel UHD 620?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, graphics-card, performance, gpu

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Laptop with **4GB RAM** and **2GB Intel Integrated UHD 620 Graphics**, with **Windows 10** operating system.

I have no start-up apps.
Whenever I start my system the background processes occupy 3/4th of RAM. And if I open Chrome with a single tab, it covers the remaining 1/4th and freezes, slows down the performance, the system will be hung for a couple of minutes and starts and hangs repeatedly.

[image]

And the GPU remains 0% usage. I know the primary application of GPU is running more powerful games at better image quality, helps with image modification, video editing, and playing high-resolution video.

[image]

But is it possible to use the GPU to run chrome? Does this help in Laptop Performance?

Comment: Do you have any other GPU in your laptop other than the Intel UHD 620 Graphics.  I wouldn’t expect Chrome to use very much VRAM so 200 MB seems about the amount I would expect.  Your screenshot clearly indicates Chrome is being hardware accelerated by your iGPU which shares your system memory.  Chrome is using nearly 33% of your system memory which explains why your performance is so bad.

Comment: No, I don't have any other GPU. Yes, I don't know the reason, but chrome uses more than 33%

Comment: Also I tried uninstalling chrome and re-installing, but I have the same issue

Comment: Web browsers, are no longer considered “light computing”, that hasn’t been the case for years.  Chrome is using nearly 800 MB because you have 20 tabs open (according to your screenshot). Your system needs more memory.

Comment: No, I just opened chrome to take the screenshot and add it here, Single tab. I rarely go with 4 tabs as my installed ram is very low

Comment: I will word my comment another way, Chrome on your system is already using your iGPU, has 20 processes, and using nearly 800 MB of your 4 GB of system memory.  Your performance issues are due to the low amount of memory in your system.  Based on the information you provided above there is no solution to that problem.  Chrome is already using your GPU to decode video (or 3D processing per the screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

The HD 620 integrated adapter does not have a dedicated graphics memory or
an eDRAM cache, so it has to access the main memory.
In other words, it uses the computer's memory for graphical memory.

The HD 620 is capable of using up to 32 GB of your memory, but usually
does not go beyond half of it.

I do not know upon what you base the 2 GB figure for the HD 620,
but if true, this does not leave much memory for Windows and your
applications.

If you have another GPU, using it will reduce somewhat the memory usage
of the HD 620.

What will help the most is to add more RAM to your computer.

Comment: Shared GPU Memory 2GB...